# Random number bigger than 100,000

Tags: c++, c, random, numbers

I'm writing in C/C++ and I want to create a lot of random numbers which are bigger than 100,000. How I would do that? With `rand();`

Comment: They must *all* be larger than 100,000? Its important, so please clarify.

Comment: Yes they should be larger than 100,000

Comment: Bigger than 100,000 and smaller than... ?

Comment: don't mind. just bigger than 100.000

Comment: Make an ordinary random number and add 100000?

Comment: You have to choose a maximum. Anyway your variable's type will inherently have a maximum. You could use `limits` to find the maximum value for your type, and make sure you don't exceed it.

Comment: Its getting weird because if use i = rand() i always get the same result. (16807)

Comment: Make sure to give srand() and different value on each execution or you'll start at the same point in the psuedorandom sequence and get the same results in every execution. That's why I suggested `srand(clock());` Using clock() isn't highly secure but you probably are not worried about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Initialize rand()'s sequence. A typical seed value is the return value of time()
srand(someSeedValue);

//...

long range = 150000; // 100000 + range is the maximum value you allow
long number = 100000 + (rand() * range) / RAND_MAX;
```

You may need to use something larger than a long int for `range` and `number` if `(100000 + range)` will exceed its max value.

Comment: I get the same value (100001)

Comment: @user776720 I assume you seeded with `srand()` ?

Comment: Try with the parens I added to make sure the multiplication happens first.

Comment: Make sure `long` has a greater range than `RAND_MAX`, or this will overflow.

Comment: Extra parentheses are not needed here. The multiplication will happen first by definition.

Comment: `Extra parentheses are not needed here.` That what I thought, @amaurea, but others' comments claimed otherwise. Perhaps it was overflow instead.

Comment: @wardd: Note that `range` is `long`. If `long` is longer than `int`, then the calculation will not overflow as long as the actual value of `range` is less than `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Seed with time(), not clock(). The latter will normally start from 0 when you start the program, so you'll probably be seeding with the same, low number/numbers every time.

Comment: Why not simply use `number = 100000 + rand() % range;` if you have a hard range ceiling. You already know `rand()` can reach RAND_MAX. Its presence in the equation (RAND_MAX) seems pointless.

Comment: @WhozCraig numbers generated using % range will form not uniform distribution (less number will have higher probability) therefore concept of random numbers will be violated.

Comment: @spin_eight So by that the seemingly simple `rand() % 6` for a simple dice roll is, in fact weighted to the lower numbers? where exactly is the cutoff? It is based on the PRNG algorithm? I'm just imagining all those `rand() % N` usages out there floating in space that are all, by your point, not random in their range. I'd like a cite for a proof, in fact, as given a acceptable random source, I fail to make the connection at all. [This](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html) seems to move into your point, however, so my disconnect isn't necessarily solo, to be sure.

Comment: Ok, here it is: suppose we want generate random numbers in range [0,2], let`s for simplicity take that rand_max = 10, so using you method we should write: number = rand() % 3;
Let`s see that we shall get: 0 : 0,3,6,9 (4 values), 1 : 1,4,7,10 (4 values), 2:(2,5,8). So as 0 and 1 will be generated in 4 cases and 2 only in 3 cases we probability of 2 is less than one of 0,1. We higher max_rand the greate the bias from uniform distribution

Comment: @spin_eight Totally understand. From what I see it is addressable so long as your range distance is a whole divisor of RAND_MAX+1, which in your sample case is not. Choosing a range of [0,2] (dist=3) and rand_max=8, you have 0:(0,3,6), 1:(1,4,7), 2:(2,5,8). I concur unless your range instance is an even divisor of rand_max+1, you're absolutely right, it will definitely skew the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You wouldn't do that with `rand`, but with a proper random number generator which comes with newer C++, see e.g. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

```
const int min = 100000;
const int max = 1000000;
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min,max);
int random_int = distribution(generator);  // generate random int flat in [min, max]
```

Don't forget to properly seed your generator.

Above I imply that `rand` is not a "proper" pseudo-RNG since it typically comes with a number of shortcomings. In the best case, it lacks abstraction so picking from a different distribution becomes hard and error-prone (search the web for e.g. "random range modulus"). Also replacing the underlying engine used to generate the random numbers is AFAIK impossible by design. In less optimal cases `rand` as a pseudo-RNG doesn't provide long enough sequence lengths for many/most use cases. With TR1/C++11 generating high-quality random numbers is easy enough to always use the proper solution, so that one doesn't need to first worry about the quality of the used pseudo-RNG when obscure bugs show up. Microsoft's STL gave a presentation giving a nice [summary talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)  on the topic at GoingNative2013.

Comment: thnx for info! You state that rand not a proper random number generator, could you support you words with some arguments / links?

Answer (score 2):

In general you can use a random number generator that goes between 0 and 1, and get any range you want by doing the following transformation:

```
x' = r x + b
```

So if you want random numbers between, say, 100,000 and 300,000, and `x` is your random number between 0 and 1, then you'd set `r` to be 200,000 and `b` to be 100,000 and `x'` will be within the range you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the C++ builtins yet, Boost has a bunch of real randomizers in [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_random.html), including [specific solutions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html#boost_random.tutorial.generating_integers_in_a_range) for your apparent problem space.

I'd echo the comments that clarifying edits in your question would improve the accuracy of answers eg. "I need uniformly-distributed integers from 100,001 through 1,000,000".