# getting random numbers larger than RAND_MAX

Tags: c++

Question 7-9 of *Accelerated C++* by Andrew Koenig asks:

> 7-9. (difficult) The implementation of nrand in §7.4.4/135 will not
>   work for arguments greater than RAND_MAX. Usually, this restriction is
>   no problem, because RAND_MAX is often the largest possible integer
>   anyway. Nevertheless, there are implementations under which RAND_MAX
>   is much smaller than the largest possible integer. For example, it is
>   not uncommon for RAND_MAX to be 32767 (2^15 -1) and the largest
>   possible integer to be 2147483647 (2^31 -1). Reimplement nrand so that
>   it works well for all values of n.

If `n > RAN_MAX` my thoughts are to take

```
double temp = n/RAN_MAX + .5;
int mult = temp;
int randomNum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i != mult; mult++)
    randomNum += rand();
```

then test to see if randomNum < n.  Would this work to generate a random number `> RAND_MAX`?  I don't know how to use larger integers than my computer can handle, so I don't think there is any real way to tell.

Comment: Suppose you roll two dice and add the results. Is 12 as likely as 7?

Comment: Any thoughts on an approach to this problem?

Comment: Suppose I rolled one die, multiplied the result by 6, then added the result of rolling a second die. Would that be better?

Comment: Oh, I see :).  Now i'll try to expand it to my problem.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't just concatenate the bits?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : Because that assumes `RAND_MAX` has the form `(1<<N) -1`, which may not be true. Ignoring the minimum of 32767 for a moment, let's assume it's 5. Outcomes 6 and 7 are then impossible, as are 14 and 15, etcetera. You skip straight from 5 to 8, from 13 to 16.

Answer (score 4):

If you're truly mucking with integers larger than your computer can handle, that's, well, complicated.

But you do have several options for integers big than `int`, these include: `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long` in increasing order of bigness. Just how big the numbers become various depending on your architecture.

For instance, on my machine I have the following:

```
Data Type:   Bytes  Minimum               Maximum
Short SInt:  2      -32768                32767
Short UInt:  2      0                     65535
UInt:        4      0                     4294967295
SInt:        4      -2147483648           2147483647
ULong:       8      0                     18446744073709551615
SLong:       8      -9223372036854775808  9223372036854775807
ULong Long:  8      0                     18446744073709551615
SLong Long:  8      -9223372036854775808  9223372036854775807
```

So, as you can see, you can make numbers much larger than `int` and 32767.

One way to do this is as follows:

```
double a=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
unsigned long long random_n=(unsigned long long)(BIG_MAXIMUM_NUMBER*a);
```

However, due to the discrete nature of floating-point numbers, this may mean that some values will just never show up in your output stream.

C++11 has a  library which solves both this problem and the problem you mention. An example of its usage is:

```
const int min = 100000;
const int max = 1000000;
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min,max);
int random_int = distribution(generator);
```

Just change the data types to suit your big needs.

Another way to look at this is that we can interpret `rand()` as returning a bit-field and that, since it is a uniform PRNG, all bit-fields are equally likely. We can then just make multiple calls to `rand()` to get multiple equally-likely bit-fields and merge these to make big numbers. Here's how we would do this to make a 16-bit random number from two 8-bit random numbers:

```
uint16 a=(uint16)(rand()&255);
uint16 b=(uint16)(rand()&255);
uint16 random_int=b<<8 | a;
```

The `rand()&255` keeps only the 8 least significant bits of whatever number `rand()` returns; that is, it keeps only the last byte of `rand()`.

The `(uint16)` casts this byte into an unsigned 16-bit number.

`a<<8` shifts the bits of `a` 8 bits to the left, which makes room to safely add `b`.

But what if `rand()` returns a signed-value, such that the most-significant bit is always 0 or 1? We can then do the following:

```
uint16 a=(uint16)(rand()&255);
uint16 b=(uint16)(rand()&255);
uint16 c=(uint16)(rand()&1);
uint16 random_int=c<<14 | b<<7 | a;
```

We left-shift `b` only 7-bits so that the 8th least significant bit is random. This means the 14th and 15th least significant bits will be non-random. Since we want to mimic the behaviour of `rand()`, we leave the 15th least significant bit non-random, and grab a single random bit to left-shift into the 14th LSB's place.

Comment: When you copied above use of `uniform_int_distribution` out of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503671/random-number-bigger-than-100-000/13503714#13503714 you dropped the note on seeding the generator. This is probably important.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier, the note is merely that the generator should be properly seeded. As should cstdlib's `rand()`. Discussing that likely diverges from the point of interest here.