# Generating a very large random number and storing it in string buffer and writing it to file

Tags: c, file, random

I'm making a C code that generates a very large random number(say 50 digits), and then store it in the string buffer and copy this to a text file. 
Please refer the code that I have written for the same:

```
FILE *fp;
char first_num[MAX];
char second_num[MAX];
char *answer;
int i,test_cases,numbers;


fp = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
if(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    exit(1);
}  
printf("How many number combinations you wish to enter?\n");
scanf("%d",&numbers);
for(i=0;i<(2*numbers);i++)
{
    char buf1[50], *number;
    number = rand() % 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    sprintf(buf1, "%s", number);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buf1);
}

fclose(fp);
```

But I get a floating point exception and my code is dumped.
Can anyone help me out in the same. I'm actually trying to multiply those random numbers once they are stored in the file as strings.

Comment: number is declared as a char pointer!

Comment: you didn't understand my hint.....

Comment: You could also just use the *openssl* library and generate a sha512 sum on a string or file and take any 50 digits you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char buf1[50], *number;
number = rand() % 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
```

First, `number` is a `char *` and `rand` returns `int`. Second, since `int` can't hold more than 2 ***to the power of 32*** - 1, using modulo with such a high number (10^???) is useless. I would suggest looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503671/random-number-bigger-than-100-000) for a portable solution for 64-bit numbers, but it's still lower than what you tried

**EDIT:** second option, that would enable you to generate as-big-as-you-want numbers can be this:

1. create a large array (number of digits)
2. generate random digit ( 0 <= x <= 9)
3. append this digit to array
4. repeat until you have the number of digits you want

***EXAMPLE:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
time_t t;
int i = 0;
srand((unsigned) time(&t));

const int SIZE = 1500;
char num[SIZE];
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    num[i] = (char)(rand() % 10 + 48);
num[SIZE] = '\0';
printf("%s", num);
getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you concatenate in one string several randomly generated `unsigned int` up until you have a "number" with the right number of digits?

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a character array, `digits[]` long enough to hold your number and the terminating \0.
2. Pick a random character in the range '1'..'9' and put it in `digits[0]`.  This avoids leading zeros.
3. Pick a random character in the range '0'..'9' and put it in the next vacant position in `digits[]`.
4. Repeat #3 until `digits[]` has only the last slot unfilled.
5. Insert the terminating \0 into the last position of `digits[]`.

You now have your large number in a character array/string.  I assume you can write a string to a file.